# How to get only holiday date from date array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to make a holiday array, it is based on `work_day`.

For example is if in 1 group there's only day 1-2 (sunday-monday), then the other day (tuesday-saturday) is holiday. And based on that days, I want to get a holiday date array from start of the year until now.

I have a table like this:

```
attendance_group_id | day
GROUP-001           | 1
GROUP-001           | 2
GROUP-002           | 1
GROUP-003           | 1
```

What I've done first is getting all data from `work_day` table using code bellow:

```
foreach ($group_work_hour as $hours) {
   foreach ($hours as $hour){
     $work_day = (object) array();
     $work_day->group_id = $hour->attendance_group_id;
     $work_day->day = $hour->day;

     $work_day_arr[] = $work_day;
   }
}
```

And the result from code above is like bellow, every group can have day up to 7 day (1-7). 1 for sunday and 7 for saturday.

**Array work day**

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 4,
  ),
  3 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 5,
  ),
  4 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 6,
  ),
  5 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 7,
  ),
  6 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 2,
  ),
  7 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 3,
  ),
  8 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 4,
  ),
  9 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 5,
  ),
  10 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 6,
  ),
```

And what I've done next is to get every date from start of the year until today and store it to an array.

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');                   
$start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($now)->startOfYear()->format('Y-m-d');

$dateRangePeriod = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($start, $now);
$dateRange = [];
foreach ($dateRangePeriod as $key => $date) {
    $dateRange[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

The result from code above is like this:

**Array date**

```
array (
  0 => '2022-04-01',
  1 => '2022-04-02',
  2 => '2022-04-03',
  3 => '2022-04-04',
  4 => '2022-04-05',
  5 => '2022-04-06',
  6 => '2022-04-07',
  7 => '2022-04-08',
  8 => '2022-04-09',
  9 => '2022-04-10',
  10 => '2022-04-11',
  11 => '2022-04-12',
  12 => '2022-04-13',
)
```

What I want to do next is, I want to get only holiday date from `array date` above. But I don't know how to do that because from `work_day` I only get `group_id` and `the number of day`.
How to know if the day from array date is the holiday based on array `work_day`.

I'm trying some way to doing it, but I can't found the solution yet. I've tried like code bellow, but still not working:

```
// Loop all date from array date
foreach ($dateRange as $range) {
            // Get number of day from date
            $day = date('N', strtotime($range));

            // Loop work day array
            foreach ($work_day_arr as $work) {
                // When day from work not equals to day from date (this is a right way to check if days from array date is a holiday)?
                if($work->day != $day) {
                   // Check if group_id & off_date (holiday date) is not set
                    if(!isset($data['attendance_group_id'], $data['off_date'])) {
                       $data['attendance_group_id'] = $work->group_id;                    
                       $data['off_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($range));
                       $objData[] = $data;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
```

The example result that I want is something like this (excluding holiday date):

```
From:
array (
  0 => '2022-04-01',  // holiday date
  1 => '2022-04-02',
  2 => '2022-04-03',
  3 => '2022-04-04',
  4 => '2022-04-05',
  5 => '2022-04-06', // holiday date
  6 => '2022-04-07',
  7 => '2022-04-08',
  8 => '2022-04-09',
  9 => '2022-04-10',
  10 => '2022-04-11',
  11 => '2022-04-12', // holiday date
  12 => '2022-04-13', // holiday date
)

To (excluding holiday date):

array (
  0 => '2022-04-02',
  1 => '2022-04-03',
  2 => '2022-04-04',
  3 => '2022-04-05',
  4 => '2022-04-07',
  5 => '2022-04-08',
  6 => '2022-04-09',
  7 => '2022-04-10',
  8 => '2022-04-11',
)
```

Another case example

```
From array work day: 
day = 1, which is Sunday

array date:
01-01-2022 
02-02-2022 // if this date == sunday, then this is a holiday
03-02-2022

result:
02-02-2022 // only get holiday date
```

Comment: I see that you've put some good effort in, but I personally cannot follow what you need help with.  When presenting array data on Stack Overflow, please use `var_export()` instead of `dd()` so that contributors can immediately use your output in their sandbox codes.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for your comment, I've updated the question. Instead of `dd` now I'm using `var_export`